# Behavior of find -mtime

Tags: find

I have the below files in directory `new`:

```
Dec 14 04:35 New_folder
Dec 13 05:50 abc.sh
Dec 13 06:33 ashutosh.txt
Dec 13 06:40 delete.sh
Dec 13 07:19 test.bat
Dec 14 04:44 test.sh
Dec 14 04:30 xyz.sh
```

And running the below command

```
find /test/new/ -type f -mtime +1
```

According to definition of this command I will get all files which are older than one day, on 14 Dec when I am running, but I am not getting any file in the output.

What is a command line that works?

Answer (score 1):

`find` rounds up to the nearest 24-hour period; this encompasses all of your files:

```
If no units are specified, this primary evaluates to true if the
difference between the file last modification time and the
time find was started, rounded up to the next full 24-hour period,
is n 24-hour periods.
```

To check this, try `touch -t` on one of your files:

```
touch -t 12011200 abc.sh
```

If you re-run your `find` command you should now see `abc.sh` (because your `touch` command set the last access/modification time of `abc.sh` to be December 1st, at 12:00).